# php dropdown list sort

Tags: php, list, sorting, dropdown

I am displaying in a dropdown menu a list of values and the problem is that I cannot sort them.

Every option has a value e.g. dog->15 cat->17 apple->22 chair->32

I have tried to use the arsort or usort for defined function but nothing works.

Here is the part of displaying the values

```
<div class="categoryselect">
<?php echo $this->lists['catid']; ?>
</div>
```

And here is where the dropdown is created

```
$lists['catid']     = JHTML::_('select.genericlist',$category,  'catid', 'class="inputtext" onchange="select_cate(this.value)"  ', 'value', 'text',$cat_id );
```

As I said I have use user defined sort functions but it seems that only the key value is affected.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Is the PHP array, associative?

Comment: @Cocest I am not sure as the list is created from a component in Joomla! so I cannot be sure

Comment: Use PHP `var_dump(lists)` and post me the result in the comment, so that I can adjust my answer in case it didn't work.

Comment: It didnt work. But I found where the list is built. https://jsfiddle.net/b1jgvw97/1

Comment: There is a mistake in my previous comment, I mean `<?php var_dump($this->lists['catid']); ?>` and post me the dump.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code below sorts the PHP associative array in ascending order

```
<div class="categoryselect">
    <?php 
        arsort($this->lists['catid']); // according to value. To sort by key use ksort(lists)
        echo $this->lists['catid']; 
    ?>
</div>
```